# Read/Write exif/jpeg on windows using c++

Tags: c++, image-processing, jpeg, exif

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I want to read/write exif/jpeg images. I know that there are some library around for this, but I am wondering if there is any library shipped with VS for this?

I need to use them in a commercial product and hence I need one that allow me t do this without buying a license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Windows GDI+ provides the Image class for working with raster images
>   (bitmaps) and vector images (metafiles). The Bitmap class and the
>   Metafile class both inherit from the Image class. The Bitmap class
>   expands on the capabilities of the Image class by providing additional
>   methods for loading, saving, and manipulating raster images. The
>   Metafile class expands on the capabilities of the Image class by
>   providing additional methods for recording and examining vector
>   images.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533815(v=vs.85).aspx

Image metadata is in the subcategory `How to read image metadata`, saying:

```
GDI+ currently supports metadata for the TIFF, JPEG, Exif, and PNG file formats.
```

Comment: Doesn't say anything about EXIF tho?

Comment: @MatsPetersson EXIF is metadata. There is a sub-catgory in the link I posted, How to read image metdata, saying that: GDI+ currently supports metadata for the TIFF, JPEG, Exif, and PNG file formats. The Exif format, which specifies how to store images captured by digital still cameras, is built on top of the TIFF and JPEG formats.