# Looking for data in EXIF format

Tags: c++, exif

I got the problem with my program made for downloading the DateTimeOrginal data from the .JPG file. I found the document about it on the internet:

https://ExifTool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html

I see that the data I'm looking for is at 0x9003 address.

So right now what I'm trying to do is:

```
temp = fopen(name, "rb");
```

open the file binary

```
fseek (temp, 0x9003, SEEK_SET);
```

move the File pointer to the address

```
fscanf(temp, "%s", str);
```

and load the data to the char[] structure.

Is atleast any of that correct? I'm still thinking that i got the problem with the address, because after compile that program i see only some trash from the file.

Comment: You are on the right track. You will need to verify that the data is compatible with a character string you are attempting to read the information into. I would suggest you download and look at the source for the program `jhead`. See: [**Exif Jpeg header manipulation tool**](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/jhead-2.97.tar.gz) It will provide an excellent example.

Comment: The value `0x9003` is not an "address", it's an Exif Tag marker. You need to [read up a bit on the Exif format](http://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html).

Comment: This might be useful too: [Read/Write exif/jpeg on windows using c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574385/read-write-exif-jpeg-on-windows-using-c)

Comment: The data you're looking for starts with the 0x9003 *tag*. It's a magic number identifying the data that follows it. You're going to have to locate the Exif data block first, then locate the part of that block which starts with that tag, and that's where the data begins.

Comment: I'm still trying to find out how to calculate it. Could you give information, where to look for it? The data should begin in the same place for every picture?

Comment: I suggest using libexif.

Comment: To be explicit, no, the data does not begin in the same place for every picture. The blocks with tags are flexible. I'd recommend https://github.com/mayanklahiri/easyexif which is only an include an a .cpp file. Took me half an hour to extract EXIF data in my program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EXIF data is embedded into the jpeg tag APP1 (0xE1).

The first thing to do is to find the jpef tag 0xE1 in the stream; you have to scan all the jpeg tags (marked by 0xFF+tag, in your case 0xFF,0xE1). After you get the tag, find its length by reading the next 2 bytes (and adjust for high endian), then get the tag's content.

After you get the tag's content, then look in it for the EXIF tag you are interested in (0x9003).

The method readStream in the jpeg class of the open source project Imebra gives you an example on how to parse jpeg tags: https://bitbucket.org/binarno/imebra/src/2eb33b2170e76b5ad2737d1c2d81c1dcaccd19e5/project_files/library/imebra/src/jpegCodec.cpp?at=default#cl-867

Answer (score 2):

Given the style of programming of the OP, I'd recommend Easyexif at https://github.com/mayanklahiri/easyexif
It's relatively easy to integrate. Note that fseek() goes to a file position; it does not search for a certain number.